# Disabling buttons while upload files in yii

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I am trying to make an upload field form in yii and when upload somewhat of a big file and press submit, I get an error of partial upload.

I understand this is because i did not let the file get uploaded properly and I do have my php.ini set properly as well to handle 20MB posts and upload as well.

What I want is when the file is being uploaded i want to change the button to something else or just remove it until file is properly uploaded.

How can i do this?

my **_form** has the following code

```
<?php
/* @var $this ImageController */
/* @var $model Image */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>
<script>
    $('input:submit').click(function(){
        $('p').text("Form submiting.....");
        $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);
    });
</script>
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'image-form',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model);?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'imageUrl'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'imageUrl',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'imageUrl'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Upload' ,array('class'=>'button')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

While my create Controller has the following code in it

```
if(isset($_POST['Image']))
        {
            //Getting the values via Post
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Image'];
            //Seeting the homeId to always be Default
            $model->homeId = self::HOME_ID;
            //Generating a new name for the file
            $fileName = mt_rand();
            //Make a FILE superglobal withthe imageUrl information
            $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'imageUrl');
            //Checking if the name is alredy taken
            $checkName = Image::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('imageUrl'=>$fileName));


            if(empty($checkName)){//If the value of the query is empty
                //Assigning the value of random number to the imageUrl
                $model->imageUrl = $fileName;
                //Assigning the value of the the extenstion to the imageExtension
                if($model->save()){
                    //Moveing the uploaded file
                    $uploadedFile->saveAs("images/upload/index/".$fileName);
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success',"File  uploaded successfully");
                }
            }else{//Display error
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error',"Please try again");
            }

        }else{
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error',"Fill in all the data");
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: You can do it with javascript/jquery. First give it a try.

Comment: I have tried the one wit the question below and its working but then its not uploading anything to the databse.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a onclick event to your Submit button which disables the button and when your upload is finished or aborted reenabled it

```
$('input:submit').click(function(){
    $('p').text("Form submiting.....");
    $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);   
});
```

Something like that yould work out of the box in yii

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
    $('form#id').submit(function(){ 
        $(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    });
", CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Hello, i am trying it out and it doesn't seem to be doing anything.I have j query libraries imported and the script is right next to the form but when choose image submit button is still there and when i press submit it still gives me that error.Do i have to change some php or anything?

Comment: posting your code would help a great deal. I'm assuming you just have the wrong dom identifier for your button so it's either binding to the wrong element or not at all.

Comment: Okay it works now had to add $(document).ready at the beginning.Now it is just giving me the form submitting which is grate but even after 5min waiting for it to upload 1.3MB file it didnt do anything.

Comment: Ahh well my fault. You have to use the submit event in this case or the form will never be submitted in the first place. use it like $('form#id').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

Comment: you should also use the yii function to register javascript like `
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
 $('form#id').submit(function(){ 
  $(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
 });
", CClientScript::POS_READY);`

Comment: $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'imageUrl'); is imageURL your fileupload field? if not you need to change that to that one. Please debug that instance first without the javascript and see if that works properly.

Comment: Sorry for late replay wasnt home. The code works as intended since when i upload a 17kb image it works but whe ni put something big like a 1mb file it fails :(

Comment: Sounds like a server error happening there. check the output of your webserver and don't forget to enable error logging for php!